# How can handle not found page for nested routing in react router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have 2 different part in my app , first part is site and the other is management panel in this case i have nested routing with react router dom but i can't handle not found page for url that is for panel ; for example i want /dashboard/something be redirect to not found page
my routing is in below :

```
<Switch>
    {/* portal */}
    <Route exact path='/' component={Portal} />
    <Route path="/landing" component={Portal} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Portal} />
    <Route path="/callback" component={Callback} />
    <Route path="/activation" component={Portal} />
    <Route path="/confirmation" component={Portal} />
    <Route path="/opportunities/:id" component={Portal} />
    <Route path='/panel' component={Portal} />
    <Route path='/electiondetails/:id' component={Portal} />
    <Route path='/errors' component={Portal} />
    {/* election panel */}
    <Route path='/electionpanel' component={Portal} />
    {/* dashboard */}
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={Index} />
    <Route path='/dashboard/login' component={Index} />
    <Route path='/dashboard/cartable/requests' component={Index} />
    <Route path='/dashboard/elections-management' component={Index} />
    {/* not found */}
    <Route path="/404" component={Portal} />
    <Redirect from="/**/" to="/404"></Redirect>
</Switch>
```

Comment: You can directly have this - ` <Route component={Portal}/>` no need to redirect. If none of the path matches above this Route then it will display Portal.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not , the environment of portal and dashboard is different i want when the url is wrong for example /dashboard/somethingwrong then redirect to a not found page but in my app when url is /dashboard/somethingwrong , white page showed and nothing load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/dashboard/something` is always matched with the following route:

```
<Route path='/dashboard' component={Index} />
```

so, you'll be presented with the `Index` component. If you'd need to pass by this route and show a 404 page you should mark it as `exact`:

```
<Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Index} />
```

Also you won't need to Redirect to that 404 page, simply just put a `Route` without `path`:

Replace

```
<Route path="/404" component={Portal} />
<Redirect from="/**/" to="/404"></Redirect>
```

with

```
<Route component={Portal} />
```

Comment: thank you very much this worked , i have a question again , now can i redirect to another not found page ? or all of the wrong url will go to same 404 page ?

Comment: @NasrinGhelichkhani salam! yes that's possible. For example in your 404 page you can render another redirect to navigate to a more specific 404 page.